# TypeError: req.formData is not a function, in next js api

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Here is the code for my nextjs route

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const config = {
  runtime: 'edge',
};

export default async function POST(req: NextRequest): Promise<Response> {
  const data = await req.formData();
  console.log(data);
  const file: File | null = data.get('file') as unknown as File;
  
  if (!file) {
    return NextResponse.json({ success: false });
  }

  return NextResponse.json({ success: true });
}
```

I am trying to send a file in the request with `Content-type: multipart/form-data` but it throws error in next js api. What am i missing? Is there something i should consider about the egde environment, i also tried to change it to node js environment but the error remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this can be qualified as an answer, but I'm looking for the same solution and just found this [discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/53827) where it explains that `req.formData()` can be handled only if you are using Next `App Routes`, instead of `Pages Routes` .. honestly, I'm not going to change the entire structure of my project, so I'm still looking for a solution, but if it helps you then there's the option

Comment: The discussion you shared was helpful, if you found any workaround let me know, i ill do the same.

Comment: NextJS is become more of a shitshow with each release.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the `req.json()` function is parsing the form data correctly. You can check in the console.

Comment: the error is , request.formData is not a function, how can i console.log it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `req.json()` instead of `req.formData`

**Your code should look like:**

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const config = {
  runtime: 'edge',
};

export default async function POST(req: NextRequest): Promise<Response> {
  const data = await req.json();
  const file: File | null = data.get('file') as unknown as File;
  
  if (!file) {
    return NextResponse.json({ success: false });
  }

  return NextResponse.json({ success: true });
}
```